# How can I see who changed the table structure?

Tags: database, postgresql, audit

Does postgresql record the schema, table, index, trigger and stored procedure changes? I don't mean the changes in data, but changes in the structure of the database.

Searching the web I always end up with data auditing solutions, which is not my problem. I do know, however, that tables and SPs are records in master tables somewhere in the database.

Is there such a log in postgresql? If not, how could I create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That type of log is not kept by default in any of the postgres tables. The closest I think you  will be able to get would be to have postgres log all `ALTER` and `CREATE` statements. Then you could look in the logs for the timestamp and specific modifications. You should be able to do that by tweaking the log_statement() parameter. More details here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT

Comment: Does that log include the user/role?

Comment: I believe you can if you modify the log_line_prefix so that every entry to the log will include the username and any other variables you want.